# Laravel - USING or NOT USING fillable in laravel model?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use this code: `Model::update($request);`, However all fields in the table might be modified by a malicious user so I change the `$fillable` in the model to modify only the ones that user can modify not others. But now the problem is that I can't modify it myself by own values.

```
id  name  verified
1   Alex     0
```

if the data the malicious user sends inside `$request` is:

```
[
    'name' => 'ModifiedAlex',
    'verified' => 1,
]
```

so it will modify the table and get verified that is not good And when setting `$fillable` to only name:

```
$fillable = [
    'name'
];
```

then I myself can't modify that with `Model::where('id', $userId)->update(['verified' => 1])`.

What to do then? Use `$fillable` or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update records by object

```php
$user = \App\User::find(1);
$user->verified = 1;
$user->save();
```

Where user is giving data you can use `Model::where('id', $userId)->update($request->except('_token'))` so it avoids any other fields.

`$request->except('_token')` gives you all the post data except the `_token` index

But for admin you can use `save` on object to **update / create** users

Answer (score 7):

**Keep using fillable and eloquent** for the malicious users.

You can use **Query Builder** to avoid the `fillable` for yourself. It doesn't check the `fillable`.:

```php
DB::table('users')->where('id', $userId)->update(['verified' => 1]); // update with verified.
```